# How to bind function arguments without binding this?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can I bind arguments to a function without binding the `this` parameter?

For example:

```
//Example function.
var c = function(a, b, c, callback) {};

//Bind values 1, 2, and 3 to a, b, and c, leave callback unbound.
var b = c.bind(null, 1, 2, 3); //How can I do this without binding scope?
```

How can I avoid the side-effect of having to bind the function's scope (e.g. setting `this` = null) as well?

**Edit:**

Sorry for the confusion. I want to bind arguments, then be able to call the bound function later and have it behave exactly as if I called the original function and passed it the bound arguments:

```
var x = 'outside object';

var obj = {
  x: 'inside object',
  c: function(a, b, c, callback) {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
};

var b = obj.c.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);

//These should both have exact same output.
obj.c(1, 2, 3, function(){});
b(function(){});

//The following works, but I was hoping there was a better way:
var b = obj.c.bind(obj, 1, 2, 3); //Anyway to make it work without typing obj twice?
```

I'm still new at this, sorry for the confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be inadequate to just re-bind `this`? `var b = c.bind(this, 1,2,3);`

Comment: Why is it problematic to have the first value of `bind()` be `null`? Seems to work fine in FF.

Comment: If the function already has this bound, using null as the first argument of bind will mess things up (i.e. bind an object method to global scope).

Comment: I'm really unclear what you're trying to do. You can't have `this` completely unbound in JavaScript. It always means *something*. So binding `this` to the `this` of the enclosing function makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm pretty new at JS. I edited the question to make it more clear. It may be that what I want isn't possible. Thanks.

Comment: When using classes, `this` is often bound to the `class` instance. So, if a `method` of a `class` is passed to another `class`, the `method` gets confused if `this` is rebound. You may want to pass the `method` onward with bound arguments without rebinding `this`, for instance as a callback or event handler.

Comment: Like come on yo, JS peeps, why you gotta give us a half-baked concept to work with? Give us a non-this bind, or let us use an alternative approach, or *something*.

Answer (score 37):

You can do this, but best to avoid thinking of it as "binding" since that is the term used for setting the "this" value.  Perhaps think of it as "wrapping" the arguments into a function?

What you do is create a function that has the desired arguments built into it via closures:

```
var withWrappedArguments = function(arg1, arg2)
    {
        return function() { ... do your stuff with arg1 and arg2 ... };
    }(actualArg1Value, actualArg2Value);
```

Hope I got the syntax right there.  What it does is create a function called withWrappedArguments() (to be pedantic it is an anonymous function assigned to the variable) that you can call any time any where and will always act with actualArg1Value and actualArg2Value, and anything else you want to put in there.  You can also have it accept further arguments at the time of the call if you want.  The secret is the parentheses after the final closing brace.  These cause the outer function to be immediately executed, with the passed values, and to generate the inner function that can be called later.  The passed values are then frozen at the time the function is generated.

This is effectively what bind does, but this way it is explicit that the wrapped arguments are simply closures on local variables, and there is no need to change the behaviour of this.

Comment: Note that this is usually called "Currying".

Comment: @M3D Capitalizing that makes it look so weird.

Comment: This would be a lot more helpful if an example was provided of how to use it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying link for anyone who is interested, although the TLDR version is "Instead of `f(x,y)` we want `f(x)(y)` or `g=f(x); g(y)`. So we would change `f=(x,y)=>x+y` to `f=(x)=>(y)=>x+y`."

Answer (score 25):

In ES6, this is easily done using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in conjunction with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

So we can define a function `bindArgs` that works like `bind`, except that only arguments are bound, but not the context (`this`).

```
Function.prototype.bindArgs =
    function (...boundArgs)
    {
        const targetFunction = this;
        return function (...args) { return targetFunction.call(this, ...boundArgs, ...args); };
    };
```

Then, for a specified function `foo` and an object `obj`, the statement

```
return foo.call(obj, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

is equivalent to

```
let bar = foo.bindArgs(1, 2);
return bar.call(obj, 3, 4);
```

where only the first and second arguments are bound to `bar`, while the context `obj` specified in the invocation is used and extra arguments are appended after the bound arguments. The return value is simply forwarded.

Comment: brings es6 to the table, still uses var :(

Comment: @DanielKobe Thanks! Spread operators and rest params were implemented in Firefox long before `let` and `const`, which weren't available yet by the time I first posted this. It's updated now.

Comment: This is great and works for callback functions! Can also be changed around to append args rather than prepend them.

Comment: Worth noting that this creates a closure each time bindArgs() is called, which means the performance is not as good as using the native bind() functionality.

Answer (score 17):

In the native [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `this` value in the result function is lost. However, you can easily recode the common shim not to use an argument for the context:

```
Function.prototype.arg = function() {
    if (typeof this !== "function")
        throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.arg needs to be called on a function");
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments), 
        fn = this, 
        partial = function() {
            return fn.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
//                          ^^^^
        };
    partial.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    return partial;
};
```

Comment: Don't like the fact that you have to play with the prototype of `Function` but it saved me a lot of time and some ugly workarounds. Thanks

Comment: @jackdbernier: You don't have to, but I find it more intuitive as a method like `bind`. You can easily transform it into a `function bindArgs(fn){ …, args = slice.call(arguments, 1); …}`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: That's what you always have to do when you care about `this` to be `a`. You might use `bind` instead, of course. Yet, the OP does explicitly *not* care about the `this` value and wanted an unbound partial function.

Comment: @Bergi: I was presuming that the purpose of not setting `this` is that the function uses `this`, but they didn't want to bind it at that moment. Also, the bit in the OP's question `//These should both have exact same output.` is contradictory to other parts of it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit about `partial.prototype = ...` line? Is it neccessary? I undestand it is for constructor functions? Is `Object.create(this.prototype)` equivalent to `Object.create(Function.prototype)` here?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: Yes, it's to make partial constructor functions work, kinda like subclassing (not that I recommend this, though). An actual `bind` doesn't work with constructors at all, the bound functions have no `.prototype`. No, [`Function.prototype !== mymethod.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 9):

```
var b = function() {
    return c(1,2,3);
};
```

Comment: In all this noisy and ambiguous answers this is a precise and helpful answer. Therefor +1.
Maybe you could refine the style of the answer as to make it more attractive to the naked eye in that fancy noisy rest of the jungle.
```const curry = (fn, ...curryArgs) => (...args) => fn(...curryArgs, args)```

Comment: Good ol' closures. Thanks for reminding me of the simpler things of life

Answer (score 7):

One more tiny implementation just for fun:

```
function bindWithoutThis(cb) {
    var bindArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return function () {
        var internalArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var args = Array.prototype.concat(bindArgs, internalArgs);
        return cb.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

How to use:

```
function onWriteEnd(evt) {}
var myPersonalWriteEnd = bindWithoutThis(onWriteEnd, "some", "data");
```

Comment: Seems like it would be more correct to pass "null" for this when invoking apply()

Answer (score 3):

May be you want to bind reference of **this** in last but your code:-

```
var c = function(a, b, c, callback) {};
var b = c.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);
```

Already applied binding for instance **this** and later you can not change it.
What I will suggest that use reference also as a parameter like this:-

```
var c = function(a, b, c, callback, ref) {  
    var self = this ? this : ref; 
    // Now you can use self just like this in your code 
};
var b = c.bind(null, 1, 2, 3),
    newRef = this, // or ref whatever you want to apply inside function c()
    d = c.bind(callback, newRef);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you ultimately want to do because the example is sort of arbitrary, but you may want to look into partials (or currying): http://jsbin.com/ifoqoj/1/edit

```
Function.prototype.partial = function(){
  var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function(){
    var arg = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++ )
      if ( args[i] === undefined )
        args[i] = arguments[arg++];
    return fn.apply(this, args);
  };
};

var c = function(a, b, c, callback) {
  console.log( a, b, c, callback )
};

var b = c.partial(1, 2, 3, undefined);

b(function(){})
```

Link to John Resig's article: http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: This function does not work, you can't call a partially applied function more than once.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you elaborate on that a bit or post a jsbin example?

Comment: See [this example](http://jsbin.com/ifoqoj/6/edit). Also, your `partial` needs to be called with `undefined` arguments to work - not what one would expect, and broken on functions that take an arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your answer. It's close to what I want, but I think the `this` object still gets messed up. Take a look at: http://jsbin.com/ifoqoj/4/edit

Comment: Ohhh, gotchya. That example makes it much clearer what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty new at JS. I also added the clarification to the main question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using **LoDash** you can use the `_.partial` function.

```js
const f  = function (a, b, c, callback) {}

const pf = _.partial(f, 1, 2, 3)  // f has first 3 arguments bound.

pf(function () {})                // callback.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `protagonist`!

```
var geoOpts = {...};

function geoSuccess(user){  // protagonizes for 'user'
  return function Success(pos){
    if(!pos || !pos.coords || !pos.coords.latitude || !pos.coords.longitude){ throw new Error('Geolocation Error: insufficient data.'); }

    var data = {pos.coords: pos.coords, ...};

    // now we have a callback we can turn into an object. implementation can use 'this' inside callback
    if(user){
      user.prototype = data;
      user.prototype.watch = watchUser;
      thus.User = (new user(data));
      console.log('thus.User', thus, thus.User);
    }
  }
}

function geoError(errorCallback){  // protagonizes for 'errorCallback'
  return function(err){
    console.log('@DECLINED', err);
    errorCallback && errorCallback(err);
  }
}

function getUserPos(user, error, opts){
  nav.geo.getPos(geoSuccess(user), geoError(error), opts || geoOpts);
}
```

Basically, the function you want to pass params to becomes a proxy which you can call to pass a variable, and it returns the function you actually want to do stuff.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous user posted this additional info:

> Building on what has already been provided in this post -- the most elegant solution I've seen is to *Curry* your arguments and context:

```
function Class(a, b, c, d){
    console.log('@Class #this', this, a, b, c, d);
}

function Context(name){
    console.log('@Context', this, name);
    this.name = name;
}

var context1 = new Context('One');
var context2 = new Context('Two');

function curryArguments(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function bindContext() {
      var additional = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      return fn.apply(this, args.concat(additional));
    };
}

var bindContext = curryArguments(Class, 'A', 'B');

bindContext.apply(context1, ['C', 'D']);
bindContext.apply(context2, ['Y', 'Z']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for the exemple you gave, this will do

```
var b= function(callback){
        return obj.c(1,2,3, callback);
};
```

If you want to guarenty enclosure of the parameters :

```
var b= (function(p1,p2,p3, obj){
        var c=obj.c;
        return function(callback){
                return c.call(obj,p1,p2,p3, callback);
        }
})(1,2,3,obj)
```

But if so you should just stick to your solution:

```
var b = obj.c.bind(obj, 1, 2, 3);
```

It's the better way.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple like that?

```
var b = (cb) => obj.c(1,2,3, cb)
b(function(){}) // insidde object
```

More general solution:

```js
function original(a, b, c) { console.log(a, b, c) }
let tied = (...args) => original(1, 2, ...args)

original(1,2,3) // 1 2 3
tied(5,6,7) // 1 2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function:

```
function bindArgs(func, ...boundArgs) {
    return function (...args) {
        return func(...boundArgs, ...args);
    };
}
// use
const deleteGroup = bindArgs(this.props.deleteGroup, "gorupName1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a wrapper around the function to save this as mythis ?

```
function mythis() {
  this.name = "mythis";
  mythis = this;
  function c(a, b) {
    this.name = "original";
    alert('a=' + a + ' b =' + b + 'this = ' + this.name + ' mythis = ' + mythis.name);
    return "ok";
  }    
  return {
    c: c
  }
};

var retval = mythis().c(0, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery 1.9 brought exactly that feature with the proxy function.](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

> As of jQuery 1.9, when the context is null or undefined the proxied function will be called with the same this object as the proxy was called with. This allows $.proxy() to be used to partially apply the arguments of a function without changing the context.

Example:

```
$.proxy(this.myFunction, 
        undefined /* leaving the context empty */, 
        [precededArg1, precededArg2]);
```

Answer (score -6):

Jquery use case:

instead:

```
for(var i = 0;i<3;i++){
    $('<input>').appendTo('body').click(function(i){
        $(this).val(i); // wont work, because 'this' becomes 'i'
    }.bind(i));
}
```

use this:

```
for(var i = 0;i<3;i++){
    $('<input>').appendTo('body').click(function(e){
        var i = this;
        $(e.originalEvent.target).val(i);
    }.bind(i));
}
```