# How to pass variable to a nested callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `request` npm to get http pages. I have something like that

```
function callbackFunction1() {
  var p = 'foo';

  request(url, callbackFunction2);
}

function callbackFunction2(err, response, body){

}
```

How could I pass the variable `p` as parameter of the callbackFunction2?

Comment: You can put the p variable outside the first callbackFunction1, then use it, as a normal variable, inside callbackFunction2.

Comment: This will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851088/how-to-bind-function-arguments-without-binding-this

Comment: What is `p` in this situation? Are you looking to simply completely replace the `body` parameter or are you looking to pass it in as an extra parameter?

Comment: I'm looking to pass an extra paramter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@facebook 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581299/how-to-pass-variable-to-a-nested-callback-function/25583409#comment39954707_25581299) is they way to go.

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
request(url, callbackFunction2.bind(p));
...
console.log(this); // p
```

Read @facebook 's link to see how to do it without messing `this` if it matters in your use case.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to give all 3 parameters.

You can pass an anonymous function as second parameter like bellow

```
request(url, function(err, response, body){
    callbackFunction2(err,response, body, p);
});
```

Comment: think you need to also take err and response as parameters in the anonymous callback function

Comment: the parameters of callbackFunction2 are three then I should pass four parameters

Comment: @Mazzy I got confused a bit, why should you pass 4 parameters, when the function expects just 3 parameters, how will you use that?

Comment: the request callback function takes three parameters https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

Comment: @MatthiasPosch is correct that all three parameters followed by the fourth local parameter need to be passed to your original callback. It doesn't really make sense *not* to define your callback inline unless it's being reused by other callbacks to `request`. Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/56p9nxv5/, open the console to see the outputs.