# Using bind for partial application without affecting the receiver

Tags: javascript, partial-application, function-binding

If I want to partially apply a function I can use `bind`, but it seems I have to affect the receiver of the function (the first argument to `bind`). Is this correct?

I want to perform partial application using `bind` without affecting the receiver.

```
myFunction.bind(iDontWantThis, arg1); // I dont want to affect the receiver
```

Comment: You cannot. Use a different `partial` function, not `bind`.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [How to bind function arguments without binding this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13851088/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> partial application using `bind` without affecting the receiver

That's not possible. `bind` was explicitly designed to partially apply the "zeroth argument" - the `this` value, and optionally more arguments. If you only want to fix the first (and potentially more) parameters of your function, but leave `this` unbound, you'll need to use a different function:

```
Function.prototype.partial = function() {
    if (arguments.length == 0)
        return this;
    var fn = this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

Of course, such a function is also available in many libraries, e.g. [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#partial), [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#partial), [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partial) etc. There is no native equivalent however.