# How to assign a function with parameters without executing it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My objective is to change the border style of button elements when they are clicked with javascript. I made a function `setBorder` and assigned to the onclick event on all button elements as:

```
function setBorder(myobj) {     
            myobj.style.borderStyle = "inset";
        }  
var menubtn = document.getElementById("menu_btn");
menubtn.onactive = setBorder(menubtn);
```

The problem here is that the border style is changed as soon as the page loads because when javascript is parsed the function `setBorder()` is executed due to the brackets `()`. Another alternative I thought was:

```
function setBorder() {      
            this.style.borderStyle = "inset";
        }  
var menubtn = document.getElementById("menu_btn");
menubtn.onactive = setBorder;
```

I thought `this` would take the object `menubtn` -- but this didn't happen. Why didn't `this` take the object `menubtn`?

I think there could be a way in which `setBorder` could be linked as the prototype object of all button elements. The prototype object would have a function `func_SetBorder` as it's property. Then we could call the `func_setBorder` as:

```
menubtn.onclick = menubtn.func_setborder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in JavaScript, when you use `this` keyword inside function in `this` it will points to an object on which you call your function. So, you have your function like this

```
function myFunc() {
    this.do_smth;
}
```

and then you call it: `my_obj.myFunc()`, then, inside your `myFunc` `this`will points to `my_obj`.

Assume that you want to call your function with another object:

```
obj_foo.myFunc()
```

In this case `this` inside your function will points to `obj_foo`

If you want to call your function with different objects (but you must be sure that your objects have yhe same properties) its better to use `call/apply` or `bind`.

`bind` will say to your function "this is the scope which you should work with". But you should always bind your function to different objects in case of using `this`. More pretty and safely way is to use `call/apply`. You also should call your function with `call/apply` each time like with `bind`, but it looks more better.

So, your code should be like this: `setBorder.call(menubtn)`

Comment: Seems like someone downvoted your answer for no answer. Anyways thanks for explaining.

Comment: The last line is incorrect. It is calling the function, and assigning the undefined return value as the callback.

Comment: @user31782, hope that helps :)

Comment: But now how would `setBorder.call(menubtn)` get executed with the `onactive` event?

Comment: @user31782 try this `menubtn.onactive = function() { setBorder.call(menubtn) }`

Comment: @Andrew, the proper way of achieving that behavior would be to use `.bind()` as mentioned by @Delapouite.

Comment: @fvargas, maybe, I did not say that this is the right way :) but if he wants to use one function with more than one object - that's the choise of @user31782 how to achive this, with `call` or with `bind`

Answer (score 2):

This solution achieves what you're looking for via the use of a [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
var buttons = [ ... ];   // An array containing the buttons

for (let b of buttons) {
  b.onactive = onActive(b);
}

function onActive(button) {
  return function () {
    button.style.borderStyle = 'inset';
  }
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have 23 buttons on a website then I'll have to write the function definition 23 times. Isn't there any way the function would be defined only once and could be called 23 times?

Comment: So the trick is to use the function in the return statement. So when the parser sees  `b.onactive = onActive(b)` -- it executes `onActive(b)`, which just returns the function to `b.onactive`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is binding or binding arguments. Javascript provides a native way to bind a function. If you want to bind arguments only, you can use this method as quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13851345/2346893):

```
Function.prototype.arg = function() {
    if (typeof this !== "function")
        throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.arg needs to be called on a function");
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments), 
        fn = this, 
        partial = function() {
            return fn.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
//                          ^^^^
        };
    partial.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    return partial;
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
function setBorder(myobj) {     
            myobj.style.borderStyle = "inset";
        }  

var menubtn = document.getElementById("menu_btn");
menubtn.onactive = setBorder.arg(menubtn);
```

Or:

```
function setBorder() {     
            this.style.borderStyle = "inset";
        }  

var menubtn = document.getElementById("menu_btn");
menubtn.onactive = setBorder.bind(menubtn);
```

Answer (score 1):

By **CSS**

```
#menuBtn:active{
   border-style:inset;
}
```

By **Javascript**

You should try the `eventlistener` property as

`menubtn.addEventListener("mousedown", setBorder);`

`menubtn.addEventListener("mouseup", removeBorder);`

and inside the `setBorder` and `removeBorder` function you can use `this`

Comment: This is not working. And why would `this` work inside setBorder now?

Comment: Instead of `active` listen for `click` event and this will work perfectly. I have edited my answer with the same

Comment: Yes, now it works. I also got why `this` takes the object now because as `Andrew` explained it is called with the object `obj.function`.

Comment: Actually I want the border to be styled for the _active_ state. The _click_ event leaves the border styled forever. Does `menubtn.addEventListener("active", setBorder);` exist? Can I use `active` state here? Also I can't accept your answer because you have just given an alternative way to acheive the result. I am looking for explanatory answer. `+1`

Comment: You can achieve this by using `focus` and `blur` event in javascript. But there is a nice solution to this problem by CSS. I have edited my answer for your need

Comment: I know it with CSS. I don't want to use it for `focus` state. I want only for `active` state so that once the click button of mouse is release the border style become what it was before.

Comment: So use `:active` in css in place of `:focus`

Comment: If you're looking for a javascript solution, see my answer which uses a function closure. Otherwise, if you just want a set of buttons to have the same active state, @Ankit is right that useing `:active` on a CSS class is the way to go. You would apply that class to all of your buttons.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I think in javascript for `active` state we have to use `onmousedown` event rather than `focus` and `blur` event.

Comment: Yes, I understood your requirement is not to get for focus or blur. You need it when the button is in pressed state. For that `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` will work

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a variable.

```
var functionName = function () { 
   //things
}
```

Comment: After this how would I call the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `this` to be `menubtn` in the `setBorder` function, you need to bind it :

`menubtn.onclick = setBorder.bind(menubtn)`