# Javascript forEach returning "undefined" as object variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying implement a simple call to `forEach` to run the `logMe` function on all items in the automobiles array. The output is unexpected. All variables read "undefined."

```js
    function Automobile(year, make, model, type) {
      this.year = year;
      this.make = make;
      this.model = model;
      this.type = type;
    }

    Automobile.prototype.logMe = function(boolVal) {
      if (boolVal == true) {
        console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model + ' ' + this.type);
      } else {
        console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model);
      }
    }

    var automobiles = [
      new Automobile(2010, "Toyota", "Tacoma", "Pickup"),
      new Automobile(2005, "Lotus", "Elise", "Roadster"),
      new Automobile(2008, "Subaru", "Outback", "Wagon")
    ];

    automobiles.forEach(Automobile.prototype.logMe.bind(true)); //the problem
    automobiles[0].logMe(true); //test logMe function
```

The output:

undefined undefined undefined

undefined undefined undefined

undefined undefined undefined

1995 Honda Accord Sedan

Comment: Related: "[How to bind function arguments without binding this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13851088/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `Function.bind()` is the value for `this` within the function. In your sample, `this` is bound to `true`, which is why you get `undefined` for the property values.

`forEach` will pass the element as the first argument to the callback. Thus, instead of passing a bound method, you can define a lambda that calls `logMe` on its 1st argument.

```
automobiles.forEach(function(car, i, cars) {car.logMe(true);});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what these three variables are?

Comment: Can you clarify what these three variables are? (car, i, cars) car = the object at the index, i = the index, what is cars ?

Comment: @user3612719 it's the "automobiles" array. The third parameter passed to a `.forEach` callback is the array being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) **creates a new function** and you must pass in the value of *`this`* - the construct which calls the function.

If you want to create an array of functions that can be called later like this, you should be using `bind` like below, otherwise just call the function inside the `forEach`.

```
var caller = [];
automobiles.forEach(function(element) {
  caller.push(Automobile.prototype.logMe.bind(element));
}, caller);
caller[0](true);
```

Demo below:

```js
function Automobile(year, make, model, type) {
  this.year = year;
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.type = type;
}

Automobile.prototype.logMe = function(boolVal) {
  if (boolVal == true) {
    console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model + ' ' + this.type);
  } else {
    console.log(this.year + ' ' + this.make + ' ' + this.model);
  }
}

var automobiles = [
  new Automobile(2010, "Toyota", "Tacoma", "Pickup"),
  new Automobile(2005, "Lotus", "Elise", "Roadster"),
  new Automobile(2008, "Subaru", "Outback", "Wagon")
];

var caller = [];

automobiles.forEach(function(element) {
  caller.push(Automobile.prototype.logMe.bind(element));
}, caller);

caller[0](true); //test logMe function
```