# How can we pass argument to function which itself is passed as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function fun (a, b)  {
        console.log(a + ' ' + b);
        return a == b;
 }

function test(condition) {

    for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if(condition()){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we pass function fun as an argument inside function test with the argument a and b (a and b are variable). writing `test(fun('a', 'b'));` is resulting in an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind function arguments without binding this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851088/how-to-bind-function-arguments-without-binding-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `closure` like this:

```js
test(function(){ return fun('a', 'b'); });
```